# How do I look up objects from a list of objects based on a value?

Tags: terraform

I have a list of objects, each with two keys. I need to iterate through the list of objects and return the `object_id` of each object based on the subject type. My goal here is to generate two separate lists of `object_id`s so that I can pass them to two data objects and look up the display name of the respective groups/users: One list of `singleUser` `object_id`s, and one list of `groupMembers` `object_id`s.

Here is the example list of objects:

```json
primary_approver = [
    {
        object_id    = "99999-99999-99999-99999"
        subject_type = "singleUser"
    },
    {
        object_id    = "12345-12345-12345-12345"
        subject_type = "singleUser"
    },
    {
        object_id    = "22222-22222-22222-22222"
        subject_type = "groupMembers"
    },
    {
        object_id    = "33333-33333-33333-33333"
        subject_type = "groupMembers"
    },
    {
        subject_type = "requestorManager"
    }
]
```

Using Terraform's built-in [lookup](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/lookup) and [element](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/element) functions, I'm able to return single strings from a list. However, this doesn't help me to return a different value from an object in a list of objects.

Is what I'm trying to do here possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make two lists (i.e. one for singleUser, one for groupMember), each with a for loop that includes an if statement, which will decide whether to add the given value or not to the new list.
Something like this:

```
gMembers = [for object_id, subject_type in primary_approver : object_id if subject_type == "groupMembers"]
sUser   = [for object_id, subject_type in primary_approver : object_id if subject_type == "singleUser"]
```

Here is some documentation:

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for

Hope this helps.